# Moq - Verify a method was called with return type

Tags: c#, moq

I have a class:

```cs
class ClassA<T>
{
    T DoSomething();
}

class ResultWrapper<T>
{
    bool IsSuccessful;
    T Data;
}

class PerformAction<T>
{
    ResultWrapper<T> DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            var classA = new ClassA<T>();
            var result = new ResultWrapper<T>();
            result.Data = classA.DoSomething();
            result.IsSuccessful=true;
            return result;
        }
        catch(exception)
        {
            var result = new ResultWrapper<T>();
            result.IsSuccessful=false;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

With MOQ library, when we want to verify if a method is called, we use

```
Mock<PerformAction<ABC>> mockObject = new Mock<PerformAction<ABC>>();
mockObject.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(),Times.Once())
```

The problem with this is, it only allows you to validate if `Something` method was called on object PerformActinon.

Of course, I can use `Assert` in actual tests on return type. But Say, I have the same method being called with different implementations `PerformAction<BCD>, PerformAction<CDF> .....`
if this mock is being used at 100 places, then I will have to assert the return type at all those 100 places.

I am looking for something as part of setup something like
`mockObject.Verify(....).VerifyReturn(...)`

So that I don't have to verify return at every place, and I can just configure it once to validate for all implementation. (Verify that the method was called and in the return `IsSuccessful` is true

Comment: I don't get your question. You cannot have multiple methods differing only in return type, so what do you want to validate here?

Comment: @KlausGütter - I updated question with more details, sorry for not being clear earlier

Comment: The return _type_ is normally verified by the compiler to be correct (if you try to assign it to a variable of that type, for instance)

Comment: I don't understand that. You verify that the dependency has been called correctly. Verifying the returned means checking the mock and what you have setup but not code under test. That seems pretty useless. Just like using an Assert for that. You should Assert on returns of the class you test not on the returns on the dependencies of that class (the mocks).

Comment: Looking again at the code i am even more confused what class are you trying to test without an actual PerformAction<T> but with a Mock instead for that?